# Bash script SFTPing into remote server and downloading files, cd into proper directory on local machine

Tags: bash, shell-script, sftp, cd-command

I have a cron on my Ubuntu server that runs this bash script daily:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn sftp user@ip
expect "password:"
send "password\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd remote_directory\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "lcd ~/dtc/data/outstanding\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "mget * \n"
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\n"
interact
```

It connects to a remote server via SFTP and downloads a bunch of files.  This is working no problem, however, I want these files to appear in a certain directory on the machine (my server) running this script.

This is what I'm attempting to do on line 8 to no avail.  How can I run this script via cron, and make sure it cds into the right directory on my server so that it places  the downloaded files into the right directory?

Comment: you can cd into the directory you want to download the files into, before executing the expect script and then totally forget the `lcd` command on line 8

Comment: You could also think about using scp instead of sftp ?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to `cd` into the directory where you want to save the files and then run the expect script, leaving out the `lcd` command from the script on line 8.